# Python: How to refer to member variables

Tags: python, class, inheritance, member

I've been learning Python on Codecademy, and I'm quite confused. I can't figure out how to refer to member variables (I hope that's what they're called). Here's a piece of code I wrote to demonstrate my confusion:

```
class Triangle(object):
    number_of_sides = 3

    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3

    def check_angles(self):
        return self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180

class Equilateral(Triangle):
    angle = 60
    def __init__(self):
        self.angle1 = self.angle
        self.angle2 = self.angle
        self.angle3 = self.angle
```

So in the Equilateral subclass, `angle1`, `angle2`, `angle3`, aren't included as parameters of `__init__`. However, in the code below, `__init__` re-initializes `model`, `color`, and `mpg`. Why is this? Shouldn't it just be inherited just like in the above code with the `Equilateral` subclass? I don't understand why they were written differently.

```
class Car(object):
    condition = "new"
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg

    def display_car(self):
        print "This is a %s %s with %s MPG." %(self.color, self.model, str(self.mpg))

    def drive_car(self):
        self.condition = "used"

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg   = mpg
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, in the code below, **init** re-initializes model, color, and mpg. Why is this?

Because the author of `ElectricCar` wants the user to be able to initialize `ElectricCar` from with four parameters.

```
ec = ElectricCar('xyz-500', 'blue', 0.5, 'boxy')
```

However, they should have passed on the arguments to the base class' `__init__` method:

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```

In the case of `EquilateralTriangle`, all the angles are the same and must be 60 degrees, so it would make no sense to be able to initialize such an object from three user-provided angles.

The same comment about the base class' `__init__` applies:

```
class Equilateral(Triangle):
     angle = 60
     def __init__(self):
         super(Equilateral, self).__init__(Equilateral.angle,
                                           Equilateral.angle,
                                           Equilateral.angle)
```

Also note that it makes little sense to initialize `Triangle` from three angles, if you're talking about the kind of space where the inner angles of a triangle add up to 180 degrees (or any fixed number). It would make more sense to pass two angles only.

Comment: `super(Equilateral, self).__init__(angle, angle, angle)`: This does not run (raises `NameError`). A method does not automatically have access to its class' namespace. If you want to access `angle`, you need to use `Equilateral.angle` or `self.angle`.

Answer (score 2):

Both implementations seem to be slightly off.  In Python a superclass' `__init__()` is **not** automatically called. You must do so explicitly.

> Shouldn't it just be inherited just like in the above code with the Equilateral subclass?

When an instance of `Equilateral` is created, `Triangle.__init__()` is never called in the above implementation. There is no automatic initializer inheritance (this would violate [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *"Explicit is better than implicit"*).

`Equilateral` probably should better read:

```
class Equilateral(Triangle):
     angle = 60
     def __init__(self):
         super(Equilateral, self).__init__(self.angle, self.angle, self.angle)
```

Same thing with `ElectricCar`:

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg, battery_type):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
        self.battery_type = battery_type
```

> I don't understand why they were written differently.

That question is hard to answer. The author either did not properly understand how Python's inheritance works or he/she had an explicit reason to not call the super class initializer.

Comment: whyd o you write `self.angle` in `Equilateral`, when  juanchopanza writes `angle`?

Comment: @AlanH: His code raises a `NameError`. In python methods don't automatically have access to class and instance variables. You need to explicitly refer to them either by using `Equilateral.angle` or `self.angle`. `self.angle` hides the fact that it is a class variable, but avoids dupiicating the class name.

Comment: @AlanH There was a mistake in my code. Please see the edit. Note that I prefer using the class name to `self` in this case, because it makes it clear it is a class variable. But that is a personal choice. `self` works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, classes work a bit like onions. The outermost layer is the 'instance' object, `self`. The layer below is the class object of which self is an instance. The layers below that are the class objects that are inherited from (the base classes).

Putting something in the class definition, like the `number_of_sides` in `Triangle`, puts something in the class object. Assigning to `self` puts something in the instance object, a different layer of the onion.

When resolving a name like `self.angle`, Python starts looking at the `self` layer. If it is not found there, it looks at the layer below, and so forth. In the Equilatoral example, `angle` is not found in `self`, but it is found in the `Equilatoral` class. `angle1` is only known in the instance variable `self`, not in the class variable `Equilatoral`.

In the Car example, the variables `model`, `color` and `mpg` are stored in the *instance*, not in the class itself. They are created when the function `Car.__init__` is called, not *inherited* by some magic code. This is by design, as Python prefers explicit over implicit behavior. As explained by juan, you must explicitly call the base class constructor to fully initialise the instance object.

At first the need to explicitly call base constructors seems onerous, but in languages that prefer implicit actions (like C++ and its derivatives), you need all sorts of syntactical nightmares to explicitly override implicit behavior. This is one reason why Python has such a gentle learning curve.